# c# translate SQL to lambda expression to get IQueryable

Tags: c#, lambda, iqueryable

would be grate if someone could help me to translate this into lambda expression or something like.

firstly introduction:
are two tables/objects:

```
OFFICE 
{officeID,
 NAME,
 another data}

WORKER
{ID,
 officeID,
 NAME}
```

There is n of offices and m of workers in each off it. (we don't know exact numbers and we don't need them)

I know `WORKER NAME`, I have to get all `OFFICES` where is at least one worker with such NAME.

So,
SQL will be somethin like this :

```
SELECT * FROM OFFICE WHERE officeID = (SELECT officeID FROM WORKER where NAME='myName');
```

(maybe could be another, I'm not sure)

Just, could someone help me get the same using types:`OFFICES`,`WORKER`, with lambda expression and IQueryable?

Comment: What `ORM` do you use? What is the name of repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Navigation Properties? If so, then you can take advantage of those and do either of the two queries below:

```
context.Office.Where(o => o.Workers.Any(w => w.Name == "myName"));
```

or

```
context.Workers.Where(w => w.Name == "myName").Select(w => w.Office).Distinct();
```

Comment: thnx, but can you expain what you mean by "context", I havet heard about such class or method...

Comment: It's an instance of the data context that the Office and Workers properties are off of. You didn't provide an example of code, so I had to make up a variable name, normally I would have used the same name you used in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query should use a JOIN.

So your lambda expression would then look like:

```
var result = (from o in context.Offices
              join w in context.Workers
              on o.officeID equals w.officeID
              where w.Name.Equals("myName")
              select o).AsQueryable<Office>();
```

Comment: good query, just to note, that `context.Workers` won't be evaluated lazily, but buffered completely. So if it is a much bigger table, than `context.Offices` - swap two tables in query

Comment: ow could you write something like this:
IQueryable<T>.where(s=>...) if it possible to get this in this way...

Comment: Yes then you should go with Brian Ball's answer.